# A numerical "coincidence"

Tags: arithmetic, continued-fractions

**Trigger warning:** Here I will get fanciful and perhaps "recreational".

One of the convergents in the continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt 3$ is $\dfrac{71}{41}$ and so we get
$$
71^2 = 5041 \approx 5043 = 41^2 \times 3
$$
Similarly, with $\sqrt 2$ we get
$$
41^2 = 1681 \approx 1682 = 29^2 \times 2,
$$
and the coincidental fact that $41$ appears early in among the convergents gives us:
\begin{align}
& 71^2\times 2 & = 10082 \\
\approx {} & 41^2\times 6 & = 10086 \\
\approx{} & 29^2 \times 12 & = 10092
\end{align}
But I think proximity of these six small multiples of large squares is somewhat unusual:
$$
\left.
\begin{align}
& 71^2\times 2 & = 10082 \\
\approx {} & 41^2\times 6 & = 10086 \\
\approx {} & 29^2 \times 12 = 58^2\times 3 & = 10092 \\
\approx {} & 38^2 \times 7 & = 10108 \\
\approx {} & 17^2 \times 35 & = 10115 \\
\approx {} & 45^2 \times 5 & = 10125
\end{align}
\right\} \quad \text{range} = 43
$$
Might this "coincidence" either be an early convergent in some higher-dimensional analog of a continued fraction or might it otherwise be "explained"?

Comment: http://oeis.org/A007913/b007913.txt might be worth a look for other bunches of small square-free parts.

Comment: I agree that the clustering of multiples of larger squares seems unusual, but why small multiples? In any case, following the suggestion of @Barry Cipra, I found another Pleiadic cluster in the following 32-range: $18490=10*43^2$, $18491=11*41^2$, $18502=22*29^2$, $18513=17*33^2$, $18515=35*23^2$, $18522=42*21^2$.  And why not include $18496=1*136^2$ as the seventh sister? I see that $41^2$ and $29^2$ are again present.

Comment: @EdwardPorcella : Let's try formatting that more legibly: $$ \left. \begin{align} & 18490 = 43^2\times 10 \\ \approx {} & 18491 = 41^2\times 11 \\ \approx {} & 18496 = 136^2 \times 1 \\ \approx {} & 18502 = 29^2\times 22 \\ \approx {} & 18513 = 33^2 \times 11 \\ \approx {} & 18515 = 23^2 \times 35 \\ \approx {} & 18522 = 21^2 \times 4 \end{align} \right\} \quad \text{range} = 32 $$

Comment: @EdwardPorcella : Note that proper notation is $3\times5$ or $3\cdot5,$ not $3*5.$ Use of an asterisk for that purpose is a workaround for occasions when you're limited to characters on the keyboard.

Comment: @EdwardPorcella, nice find (and I like the "Pleiadic cluster" name).  Note to Michael: there are a couple of typos in your reformatted version.  $33^2\times11$ should be $33^2\times 17$, and $21^2\times4$ should be $21^2\times42$. Too bad comments can't be edited; maybe you want to delete and repost.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know MathJax works as fully on comments as it does on answers.

Comment: @BarryCipra : Here's a better version:
$$\left. \begin{align} & 18490 = 43^2\times 10 \\ \approx {} & 18491 = 41^2\times 11 \\ \approx {} & 18496 = 136^2 \times 1 \\ \approx {} & 18502 = 29^2\times 22 \\ \approx {} & 18513 = 33^2 \times 17 \\ \approx {} & 18515 = 23^2 \times 35 \\ \approx {} & 18522 = 21^2 \times 42 \end{align} \right\} \quad \text{range} = 32$$ $41^2$ and $43^2$ come surprisingly close considering that they are multplied by numbers so small ($11$ and $10$). $\qquad$

Comment: @EdwardPorcella : Actually I think some of its fancier features don't work in comments.

Comment: @BarryCipra $\frac{17}{12}$ and $\frac{38}{17}$ are convergents in the continued fraction expansions of $\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt5$, respectively, and here is an 8-cluster with range = 45$$2880=24^2\cdot5$$$$2883=31^2\cdot3$$$$2888=38^2\cdot2$$$$2890=17^2\cdot10$$$$2900=10^2\cdot29$$$$2904=22^2\cdot6$$$$2916=54^2\cdot1$$$$2925=15^2\cdot13$$Most of the multiples are small, which I now see is significant: you're more surprised to see small multiples of larger squares clustering than large multiples of smaller squares.  But I guess a given range is more impressive if the clustered numbers are greater?

Comment: A numerical oddity reminiscent of this is $$ \left. \begin{array}{l} 6859 = 19^3 \\ 6860 = 7^3\times 20 \end{array} \right\} \text{ difference} = 1 $$ Thus the approximation $ \left( \dfrac {19} 7 \right)^3 \approx 20$ is far closer than you would expect with a denominator as small as $7.$ And $$ \sqrt[3]{20\vphantom{\frac11}} = 2 + \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac 1 {2 + \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac 1 {154 + \ddots}}}}} $$ If you truncate $1 + \frac 1 {154}$ to $1$ then you get $19/7. \qquad$

Comment: $$\left. \begin{align} & 13120 = 2^6\times 205 \\ & 13122 = 3^8 \times 2 \\ & 13125 = 5^4\times 21  \end{align} \right\} \quad \text{range} = 5$$

Comment: Here's one that somewhat striking, as these things go: $$ \left. \begin{align} & 8954 = 11^2 \times 74 \\ & 8957 = 13^2\times53 \\ & 8959 = 17^2\times 31 \end{align} \right\} \quad \text{range} = 5 $$ Then $19$ units above that last one is this: $$ 8978 = 67^2\times 2. $$